# Expandable UIView in ScrollView in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, expandable

How can I  make my UIViews to expandable/collapsible UIView embedded in ScrollView.
[image]

[image]

This is my mainview and when the user taps on the button the view automatically resize(+200 height) itself and the views below it will automatically adjust so as the scroll view.

**Edit:** I think I can't use TableView because I'm making a automation form like this [image]

So my idea here is that whenever the switch is turn on, the label will be added in the email form and the switch acts as the (Expande/collapse) trigger of the child of the parent.

Comment: use tableView for this kind of UI behaviour. and next time please post some code on what you tried.

Comment: I can't use tableview because each view has its own elements like view1 has  2 UITextfiel and 1 switch while view2 has 1 UITextfield and 2 slider.

Answer (score 1):

The View can be a revised version of Accordion View, You can get some ideas [here](http://innofied.com/accordion-view-ios/)

After all a table view is a collection view on scrollView, so if you have time you can make the whole functionality yourself in four simple Functions for

1. drawOuterList : to draw the outer list as fully customisable views on a scrollView
2. handleButtonForExpandingOuterList : Decide to expand or close the view.
3. drawInnerList : to draw the inner list as fully customisable views on a scrollView
4. handleButtonForExpandingInnerList : Decide to expand or close the view.

there are many other links too 
Go through these links like

1. [expandable View](http://paxcel.net/blog/expandablecollapsible-table-for-ios/)
2. [expandable tableView](http://jackkwok.github.io/JKExpandTableView/)

Answer (score 0):

If time is significant for you I advise to use on of ready solutions from cocoa controls

[cocoa control search](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=Expandable%20)

In case you want to implement this on your own yo can create table view with custom cells. Make cells of two types : 
1) fold cell 
2) expanded cell

And reload the table on didSelectRowAtIndexPath. Table view is already subclass of ui scroll view, so it will do all resize work for you

Comment: I can't use tableview because each view has its own elements like view1 has  2 UITextfiel and 1 switch while view2 has 1 UITextfield and 2 slider.